# Text Decoration not working within DIV

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, text-decorations

I have the following CSS:

```
.top-category-item  {
        height: 338px;
        background-color: black;
        position: relative;
        }

.top-category-item-copy {
        width: 100%;
        /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        /*  RGBa with 0.8 opacity */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        bottom: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
        font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
        font-size: 35px;
        line-height: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #F1F1F1;
        }

.top-category-item-copy a       {
                text-decoration: none;
                }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
    <a href="">
    <div class="top-category-item low-gutter">
    <img src="images/feature-placeholder.jpg" alt="latest-image-placeholder"/ width=100% height=100%>
    <div class="top-category-item-copy">Earlier French Quarter curfew for youths gets mixed reaction.</div>
    </div>
    </a>
```

I've searched Stack Overflow for solutions to this problem:

- Tried swapping the syntax around a little e.g. `.class-name a:link {text-decoration: none;}`
- Tried declaring a global `a {text-decoration: none;}`, this works but it feels like a workaround, not a real solution

Comment: Your CSS has the link "beneath" the class, but your HTML is the other way around. That won't work. You could add a class to the "a" itself and put your text-decoration there.

Comment: Great, this works. But... I still feel like I don't understand why my code didn't work. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Change `.top-category-item-copy a {...` to just `a {...` or reference a parent element if you don't want the rule to apply to all links on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, `top-category-item-copy` is a `div`, with an `a` as the parent.  Your CSS is saying "No text decorations for all `a` tags within `.top-category-item-copy`."

Comment: Oh! Man. I get it. So a solution with this explanation in mind would perhaps be to create a DIV within `top-category-item`, this inner DIV would then have the `a` tag around it. And I move `text-decoration: none;` over to `top-category-item`.

Comment: That would work.  If you wanted to leave your HTML as is, you could change your CSS declaration to be `a div.top-category-item-copy`.  That says "An `a` tag, containing a `div` that has the class `top-category-item-copy`.

Comment: Also, I know you said that it "feels like a workaround," but there is certainly nothing wrong with saying `a {text-decoration: none;}` especially if all (or at least most) of your links are underline-free.

Comment: Wow. Matt, thank you. Really great explanation and I understand why it wasn't working before, and how I can make it work now. Implemented and working, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this oldschool move  when i want the behavior of links to be different from the text is uses

```
.top-category-item-copy:link { text-decoration: none; }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those who might still encounter this problem, i had this same issue where the a tag was parent to my custom div tag. I didnt want the whole anchor tags in my website to be altered so i had to use the parent div class for the block of anchor tags where i was altering. The arrangement would look something like this when viewed in html:

```
    <div class="parent-div-class-for-this-block-containing-anchor-tags" "bla" "bla" "bla">

    <maybe-other-div-classes-and-ids>

    <a href="my-anchor-tag-which-i-want-to-alter" class="whatever">

    <div class="my-custom-div-class-which-refuses-to-alter-this-ahref-tag-above">
```

So my solution in the css was to use the parent div class, something like this:

```
    .parent-div-class-for-this-block-containing-anchor-tags a {
            text decoration: none;
    }
```

instead of

```
    .my-custom-div-class-which-refuses-to-alter-this-ahref-tag-above a {
            text-decoration: none;
     }
```

This will alter the text-decoration of all anchor tags in this block, rather than try to use the anchor tags of the single anchor tags which is overridden by the "whatever" class. Hope this helps someone.